# non-algebraic variety definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, schemes

In [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73945/wanted-example-of-a-non-algebraic-singularity?answertab=votes#tab-top) it was several times used the notion of a *non-algebraic variety*. and I ask myself what is non-algebraic variety by definition. I'm unsure, if it is really a standard notation, since google couldn't provide a satisfying answer. any idea what it might be?

Comment: Probably you could ask directly @AntonGeraschenko

Comment: A scheme over $k$ that is not necessarily a variety.

Comment: of course not. this is the point, I was not pretty sure, if that's exactly the definition: "a non-algebraic variety = scheme over $k$, that is is not a variety"?

Comment: @juandiegorojas this is not at all what the linked post is describing. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the linked post uses "non-algebraic variety" to mean a complex-analytic space which is not isomorphic to the analytification of any algebraic variety. Complex-analytic spaces are locally ringed spaces which are locally modeled on the vanishing locus of a finite set of analytic functions. Here's a full formal definition:

Let $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb C^n}$ be the sheaf of anayltic functions on $\Bbb C^n$. Let $U$ be an open connected subset of $\Bbb C^n$, and fix finitely many analytic functions $f_1,\cdots,f_m\in\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb C^n}(U)$. Let $V\subset U$ be the common vanishing locus of the functions. Define a sheaf of rings $\mathcal{O}_V$ on $V$ as the restriction of $\mathcal{O}_U/(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$, where $\mathcal{O}_U$ is the restriction of $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb C^n}$ to $U$. We call the locally ringed space $(V,\mathcal{O}_V)$ a model. A *complex-analytic space* $X$ is then a locally ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ so that every point $x\in X$ has an open neighborhood $U\subset X$ isomorphic as a locally ringed space to a model as described previously.

Googling "complex-analytic space" should give you more to look at.